# Query Performance for multiple IQueryable in .NET Core with LINQ

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework, linq

I am currently updating a BackEnd project to .NET Core and having performance issues with my Linq queries.

Main Queries:

```
var queryTexts = from text in _repositoryContext.Text
                         where text.KeyName.StartsWith("ApplicationSettings.")
                         where text.Sprache.Equals("*")
                         select text;

var queryDescriptions = from text in queryTexts
                                where text.KeyName.EndsWith("$Descr")
                                select text;

var queryNames = from text in queryTexts
                         where !(text.KeyName.EndsWith("$Descr"))
                         select text;

var queryDefaults = from defaults in _repositoryContext.ApplicationSettingsDefaults
                            where defaults.Value != "*"
                            select defaults;
```

After getting these IQueryables I run a foreach loop in another context to build my DTO model:

```
foreach (ApplicationSettings appl in _repositoryContext.ApplicationSettings)
{
  var applDefaults = queryDefaults.Where(c => c.KeyName.Equals(appl.KeyName)).ToArray();

  description = queryDescriptions.Where(d => d.KeyName.Equals("ApplicationSettings." + appl.KeyName + ".$Descr"))
                .FirstOrDefault()?
                .Text1 ?? "";

  var name = queryNames.Where(n => n.KeyName.Equals("ApplicationSettings." + appl.KeyName)).FirstOrDefault()?.Text1 ?? "";

  // Do some stuff with data and return DTO Model
}
```

In my old Project, this part had an execution from about 0,45 sec, by now I have about 5-6 sec..

I thought about using compiled queries but I recognized these don't support returning IEnumerable yet. Also I tried to avoid Contains() method. But it didn't improve performance anyway.

Could you take short look on my queries and maybe refactor or give some hints how to make one of the queries faster?
It is to note that `_repositoryContext.Text` has compared to other contexts the most entries (about 50 000), because of translations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one can write queries like below

```
var Profile="developer"; 
var LstUserName = alreadyUsed.Where(x => x.Profile==Profile).ToList();
```

you can also use "foreach" like below

```
lstUserNames.ForEach(x=>
                        {
                           //do your stuff
                        });
```

Comment: thanks but this is already mentioned in as answer marked post

Answer (score 2):

queryNames, queryDefaults, and queryDescriptions are all *queries* not collections.  And you are running them in a loop.  Try loading them outside of the loop.

eg: load queryNames to a dictionary:

```
var queryNames = from text in queryTexts
                         where !(text.KeyName.EndsWith("$Descr"))
                         select text;
var queryNamesByName = queryName.ToDictionary(n => n.KeyName);
```

Comment: if same code on old EF takes 0.5sec, and now 5 - 6 sec it`s still a major point of interest for EF Core team (if code the same)...

Comment: I will try this too, just changed the first four queries to use ToArray() method and then work with the arrays in further implementantion. Already reduced time to about 1,5 seconds. Code: 
`var queryDefaults = _repositoryContext.ApplicationSettingsDefaults.Where(
                d => d.Value != "*").ToArray();`

Comment: I still wonder if it would be possible to use a compiled query? because these queries are executed a lot in the project

Comment: @Vladimir old code was raw sql, but I wanted to change it using linq because of readability